# Flutter - Expansion Panel Header - Whole header clickable

Tags: flutter

I've build a list of expansion panel and I find it annoying that you have to press the arrow to expand it. Intuitively, you want to expand the panel when you click anywhere on the header (feedback from testers).

Is there a way to do it ? I don't see any properties and the header builder only allows a widget as parameter.

Comment: can you please show your code

Answer (score 6):

If you are using the `ExpansionPanelRadio` then it has a parameter called `canTapOnHeader`, make it to `true`.

Like below:

```
ExpansionPanelRadio(
  value: item.id,
  canTapOnHeader: true,
  headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
    ...
  },
  body: ...,
);
```

Comment: I don't see a `canTapOnHeader` property on ExpansionPanelRadio

Comment: Can you please edit your question with the code? and try running flutter upgrade once.